# C# Running code on open webbrowser, downloading specific files

Tags: c#, web, certificate

So this is a bit of a tricky problem I'm having and I'm starting to think that it's not easily possible.

There's a website that has a level of security that I am trying to automatically download files from(it's a banking site). The website will not save user info when you log in, and after logging in you have to verify a certificate in your browser to receive your reports. Once you've verified the browser with the certificate and are logged in, however, you are free to open up the reports(pdf files) by directly typing  in the link to them.

For other sites, I would do something like:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
  client.DownloadFile(PDFFileReportWebsite,@LocalLocationToStoreFile);
}
```

But for this site, I have no idea what to do(the above doesn't work). Is there a way to have code like above run from within the browser itself after I've logged in and verified my certificate?

One solution I thought of that would be overkill(nevermind just gross/hacky), and I can't imagine the best option, would be to make a webbrowser app in C# and run the code on that browser after logging in.

EDIT:

```
ProcessStartInfo pi = new ProcessStartInfo(WebAddressOfPdfFileINeed);
Process.Start(pi);
```

correctly opens up the webbrowser(chrome since its my default) to the file I need(If I'm already logged in and verified my cert). Is there a way to force chrome to save this file or print it as text or a pdf?

Comment: You probably need cookies.

Comment: If it matters, the certificate file is a .pfx

Comment: @SLaks
Could you expand on what you mean? Every instance of a web-browser has to reverify when getting into the site(even if the browser is logged in and open, opening up a new browser would require you to verify the certificate again to access the reports), so even if I somehow used my cookies from internet explorer(which I don't know how I would) when trying to download the files, it still would be blocked by the certificate verification.

Comment: Use chilkat dll. 
https://www.example-code.com/csharp/http_tlsMutualAuthentication.asp
Its 10 lines of code max.

Comment: @Aki003, that looks promising but it requires a license  and I can't seem to get it working on my computer anyways(keep getting a badimageexception but already doublechecked to make sure everything was consistent.)

Comment: its free for 30days, just put 'anythin for 30 days'. 
success = http.UnlockComponent("Anything for 30-day trial"); check the success variable for licence

Comment: @Aki003, this is unfortunately going to be used for much longer than 30 days, but it also still doesn't help that I couldn't get it working on my computer in the first place.